# iphone app submitting fails

Tags: iphone

I'm attempting to submit my app,
and I'm getting no record found for the app on itunesconnect...
I have added the app on itunesconnect,
and have set up all the app ID, CRS, etc.

Why could it be?

Please help me out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What state your application has?

To be able to upload a binary application must have `"Waiting For Upload"` status - you need to push `"Ready to Upload Binary"` on application page in itunes connect.